# Changing wp login url without .htaccess

Tags: plugins, admin

How to change wordpress login url without using .htaccess, should be a manual process, so `example.com/login` will not redirect to `example.com/wp-login.php` so `example.com/login` will be the login page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a post about it a few weeks ago [`WordPress Easy Login URL without  htaccess`](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-easy-login-url-with-no-htaccess),
but if you don't want to read that, then here is the code in plugin form:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Nice Login URL
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: Simple plugin to redirect login/register to a nice url
Version: 1.0
Author: bainternet
Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
*/

// Add rewrite rule and flush on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'NLURL_activate' );
function NLURL_activate() {
    NLURL_rewrite();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Flush on plugin deactivation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'NLURL_deactivate' );
function NLURL_deactivate() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// Create new rewrite rule
add_action( 'init', 'NLURL_rewrite' );
function NLURL_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'login/?$', 'wp-login.php', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'register/?$', 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'forgot/?$', 'wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'top' );
}


//register url fix
add_filter('register','fix_register_url');
function fix_register_url($link){
    return str_replace(site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login'),site_url('register', 'login'),$link);
}

//login url fix
add_filter('login_url','fix_login_url');
function fix_login_url($link){
    return str_replace(site_url('wp-login.php', 'login'),site_url('login', 'login'),$link);
}

//forgot password url fix
add_filter('lostpassword_url','fix_lostpass_url');
function fix_lostpass_url($link){
    return str_replace('?action=lostpassword','',str_replace(network_site_url('wp-login.php', 'login'),site_url('forgot', 'login'),$link));
}

//Site URL hack to overwrite register url
add_filter('site_url','fix_urls',10,3);
function fix_urls($url, $path, $orig_scheme){
    if ($orig_scheme !== 'login')
        return $url;
    if ($path == 'wp-login.php?action=register')
        return site_url('register', 'login');

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: mmm, happy to have your plugin :D

Comment: is that it redirect to `example.com/wp-login.php`?

Comment: Sir, you may not realize this but with this code, you fixed almost everything that was broken in WP, Buddy Press and woocommerce :)