# how to change wp-admin url using function file

Tags: plugins, functions, customization

```
function go_away() {
    wp_die( 'Nice meeting you, byebye.' );
}
add_action( 'login_init' , 'go_away' );
add_action( 'admin_init' , 'go_away' );
```

hello i am using this code to lock admin of wordpress but i want that person can login in admin using a custom url he is adding.

For Eg:- first of all person is logging in using www.abc.com/wp-admin or www.abc.com/wp-login.php after lock he only know the url for login

url need to be something like this.

www.abc.com/my-admin or www.abc.com/restricted-area etc

Please help me friends

Answer (score 1):

Please see this one https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4799/64458 and before ask any question do some research first. And after that ask your question/prob with your working source/code.

---

Hey I already mention it that before ask anything please do some homework by your self. That will help you to improve.

here is your questions answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78258/64458 , if you see this then you don't have to ask this one and neither you have to wait for some one that answer it for you.

Comment: HI i tried this code and with this code my admin part is restricted its fine. But if i want to login i have to remove this code i want a same wordpress login page to another url which i will set.

Comment: I update my previous answer.